# cakephp html to pdf library/component

Tags: html, pdf, cakephp, components

do you have idea about HTML to PDF library available with CakePHP, which i would like to send as email attachment.

I have some idea about TCPDF and FPDF library, but Is there any specific ones with CakePHP available, which is just include and run to use.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I havent seen one. I use TCDCF very effectively though

Extract source to /app/vendors/tcpdf/

Then in whatever controller action

```
App::import('Vendor', 'tcpdf/tcpdf');
App::import('Vendor', 'tcpdf/config/lang/eng');

$pdf = new TCPDF("L", PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->Output("test.pdf",'I');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one available as a CakePHP plugin / component:

https://github.com/coisa/CakePDF